# Drupal: off-line page theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Why does my offline maintenance page uses the Garland theme if 
I've set zen and bluemarine themes for front-end / back-end of my Drupal website ?

How can I set my offline page theme ?

Comment: Remenber that there are two separate off-line pages in drupal: one for if you've set the site to maintenance mode, and a second one that is shown if the database is actually down, in which case it can't even load any theme stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it in settings.php. Just set

```
$conf['maintenance_theme'] = 'zen';
```

This should do it (in theory).

Answer (score 1):

This is from settings.php (in your sites/default directory)

/**
 * A custom theme can be set for the off-line page. This applies when the site
 * is explicitly set to off-line mode through the administration page or when
 * the database is inactive due to an error. It can be set through the
 * 'maintenance_theme' key. The template file should also be copied into the
 * theme. It is located inside 'modules/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php'.
 * Note: This setting does not apply to installation and update pages.
 */

## 'maintenance_theme' => 'minnelli'